# Docker build failure Debian 11

Tags: docker

I have a dockerfile that build properly on a windows machine. We are trying to switch are builds and test to a Linux Debian 11. I've installed docker and the required parts on the server and tested their hello world container which works. In my docker file I am trying to download some tools which gives a strange message "
E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic Release' does not have a Release file." as stated the docker base image is Ubuntu.  I don't know how to fix this error

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU3-ubuntu-18.04

# Elevate to root to install required packages
USER root
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install unzip libunwind8 libicu60 -y

# Install SQLPackage for Linux and make it executable
RUN wget -progress=bar:force -q -O sqlpackage.zip https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2113331 \
    && unzip -qq sqlpackage.zip -d /opt/sqlpackage \
    && chmod +x /opt/sqlpackage/sqlpackage \
    && chown -R mssql /opt/sqlpackage \
    && mkdir /tmp/db \
    && chown -R mssql /tmp/db
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was our network proxy. the real error was

> Err:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic Release
> Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The
> certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the
> certificate verification. [IP: 13.90.56.68 443]
> To fix this issue in the docker script added these lines.

```
COPY "ca-bundle.crt" ../usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca-bundle.crt 
RUN update-ca-certificates
```

The ca-bundle.crt was a file that contained the corporate self signed certificate public key